# linear algebra basic question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question follows.

[image]

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Well you need to frind a $(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{matrix})$ where $(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{matrix})(\begin{matrix}2&0\\ -1&1\end{matrix})=(\begin{matrix}2&0\\ -1&1\end{matrix})(\begin{matrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{matrix})$

Answer (score 1):

$\pmatrix{2&0\\-1&1}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{2&0\\-1&1}$

means

$\pmatrix{2a&2b\\-a+c&-b+d}=\pmatrix{2a-b&b\\2c-d&d}$.

Matrices are equal means their components are equal.

What can you conclude about $b$ from the upper right components being equal?

What can you conclude about $a$ in terms of $c$ and $d$

from the lower left components being equal?